# Change style of element when real time clock is under 15 minutes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change background of div when minutes on real time clock are less than 15. here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.setInterval(function(){
  now = new Date;
c = now.getMinutes();
if (c < 15 ) {
$('#defaultCountdown').css('background': 'red');
}
}, 1000);

</script>
```

and here is link of page, where it is not going red, c < 50 is set:

http://signalsindicator.com/timer/index.html

Comment: It's really great! What is the question?

Comment: "i want to" is not a question. What's wrong with your existing code?

Comment: it is not working :)

Comment: "it's not working" is not an error message or a problem description. Have you checked your console for errors?

Comment: and answering with `it is not working` is a downvote magnet

Comment: try print a message to console log to check if anything triggers in that interval

Comment: your sample page http://signalsindicator.com/timer/index.html has a jquery noconflict setting. So you'll have to use `j('#defaultCountdown')` instead of `$('#defaultCountdown')`. Again **a quick look at your browser console** would have shown you the error, which is repeating every time the interval runs. And zeroelement's answer about using , instead of : in the .css, and the other syntax problems, also applies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
$('#defaultCountdown').css('background': 'red');
```

to

```
$('#defaultCountdown').css('background', 'red');
```

Or change it to

```
$('#defaultCountdown').css({
  'background': 'red'
});
```

```js
window.setInterval(function(){
  now = new Date;
c = now.getMinutes();
if (c < 15 ) {
$('#defaultCountdown').css('background', 'red');
}
else{
 $('#defaultCountdown').css('background', 'blue'); 
}
}, 1000);
```

```css
div{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="defaultCountdown"></div>
```

Comment: @ZarkoZivkovic Why not? It doesn't help to other peoples but it does helps to the questioner.

Comment: @ZarkoZivkovic, i updated elementzero23 answer. Please have a look.